# Maven Assembly: Setting up external svn for in-program-use

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a very specific question. The project I am on is a maven3 driven multi-module Project. The Project uses the SVN-Api to synchronize data from a repository and process it. More specifically:
A Manager, upon recieving an update call, will contact a remote svn repository and sync the files to the harddrive, where it will afterwards process them.

I want to create an appropriate folder Structure, with the assembly plugin. When I run a package command, ideally the output in the target folder would be

```
target
- data <- this is the base folder for the external repository
--- .svn <-- repository-information
--- group1 <-- subfolders on repository
--- group2
--- group3
- program.jar <-- contains java classes, executable
- config.xml  <--- config file, editable by user
- other miscalleanous files
```

So frankly, this poses a number of problems and on top of this, I don't have too much experience with the assembly plugin. What I am not quite getting is how I am able to differentiate between files that should be put into the jar and files that should be kept outside the jar.

I have read about the assembly descriptors, I have however only seen examples that either include or exclude files, none that provide information about the relative positions the files should later have in the target folder.

Thanks for your time.
Regards,
Keno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I decided to go the following (simple) way:

At startup, The program fetches the location it's jar file is at, then checks for an resource folder outside the char. If none is found, it checks out the base directory of the svn server and starts crunching numbers. This way didn't require any fiddeling with the maven pom, and it works for testing as well.